# Why Calabi-Yau manifolds should be complex?

Tags: complex-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics

I'm aware that mathematically speaking, Calabi-Yau manifolds are complex manifolds with vanishing first Chern number. However from a physics point of view, Calabi-Yau manifolds are related to the solution of Einstein's field equation in vacuum environment (i.e., with vanishing stress–energy tensor). Since Einstein's field equation is on a 4-dimensional real manifold, why Calabi-Yau manifolds are complex? Is there a "real version" of Calabi-Yau manifold?

Comment: Superficially, "algebraic geometry" works best over algebraically-closed fields, and $\mathbb C$ is the obvious choice when the underlying "arithmetical analysis" involves $\mathbb R$. Is this the sort of thing you're asking about?

Comment: Here is my understanding of the story: if you are doing 4-dimensional GR, then indeed the relevant manifold is not a Calabi-Yau but an Einstein Lorentzian manifold (I might not have the terminology quite right.) However if you are doing some form of 10d supergravity/string theory the 6d manifold you are compactifying on gets forced to be a Calabi-Yau manifold for some reason. I really have no understanding of the physics so take this with a large grain of salt.

Comment: Since you seem to be looking for physics motivation, the easiest answer is holonomy. If you compactify superstring theory on a manifold with SU(3) holonomy, then a good bit of the supersymmetry is preserved (1/4 of it). Turns out then only manifolds with SU(3) holonomy are Calabi-Yau 3-folds. Also note every complex n-manifold does have an underlying smooth 2n-manifold.

Comment: To be a little more precise, the physics of supersymmetry requires a covariantly constant spinor. This implies the SU(3) holonomy, which implies the complex structure.

Comment: My answer to another MO question might be of interest: https://mathoverflow.net/a/43603/394

Comment: Thank you all! I know that the vacuum solutions to Einstein's field equation yield Einstein manifolds, which are basically in \mathbb{R}. Is the idea of Calabi-Yau has something to do with Einstein manifolds?

Answer (score 5):

I think that one possible answer is that a Calabi-Yau manifold is a Riemannian manifold $M$ with $SU(n)$ Riemannian holonomy, where $2n=\dim_\mathbb R M$.

Such a manifold is then necessarily complex, and the Riemannian metric is the real part of a Kähler metric which has zero Ricci curvature. Since the Ricci form in complex geometry is always a representative of the first Chern class of the manifold, what you ask follows.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $n = \frac{1}{2} \dim_{\mathbb{R}} M$?

Comment: Yes, it should! :) I'll fix it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there any intuitive reason for a $SU(n)$ holonomy group instead of a real one?

Comment: I am sorry Xige, not sure to understand correctly your question. The Lie group $SU(n)$ is indeed a real Lie group!

Comment: Oh I forgot to add... Compare to $SO(n)$, $SU(n)$is "complex" in the sense that it's a subgroup a $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$. So why don't people use $SO(n)$ for holonomy groups?

Comment: People use it! But this is the group of a "generic" orientable riemannian manifold, it does not give much more restrictions than this. On the complex side, $U(n)$ is the holonomy group of a "generic" Kähler manifold. While $SU(n)$ is the "first" holonomy group in Berger's list which gives some restrictive condition on the manifold.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider other real forms of $SU(n)$; a Riemannian manifold with holonomy in such a real form will then arise as extra dimensions in string theories with reduced holonomy and a parallel spinor. The Riemannian manifold need not be complex. But the limit as you make the extra dimensions small will not be Lorentzian, unless the extra dimensions are Riemannian with a parallel spinor. To have a reduced dimension of 4 (for standard general relativity) and a total space dimension of 10 (for type A or type B string theory), you need a 6 dimensional Riemannian manifold of extra dimensions, with a parallel spinor. These conditions give you a Calabi-Yau manifold. If you ask for 7 extra dimensions, you get a G2 holonomy manifold, so extra dimensions are not always complex. There are compact Riemannian Einstein 6-manifolds beside Calabi-Yaus, but not with a parallel spinor.

Comment: Can a mare mortal understand the importance of parallel spinors here?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Since I don't know much about string theory, what does "parallel spinor" mean? Is it related to some special structure of corresponding spin group?

Comment: Lucky for you, the term "parallel spinor" is purely differential geometry, and requires no physics to understand. It refers to a section of a spinor bundle invariant under parallel transport of a spin connection. See Lawson and Michelsohn, **Spin Geometry**, Princeton U. Press, 1990 for complete details of spinors and their associated connections.

Comment: your first sentence is hard to understand. Real forms arise as extra dimensions? Real forms are Lie groups and dimensions are, well, dimensions.